# html videos not loading on iphone but load on desktop web and android

Tags: html, ios, iphone, video

I am trying to embed a video in my html page but it is not loading on the iPhone (all I get is a crossed out play button). It loads fine on the desktop and Android. It is not a browser issue because I get the same error using both Chrome and Safari on my iPhone.

```
<div id="video_container">
    <video width="400" height="400" controls preload="none" poster="/static/img/tag_logo.png">
        <source src="/static/videos/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
</div>
```

Interestingly I have tested out my code with the video from the video.js sample project. If I replace my current source tag with this the video loads:

```
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

However, I also downloaded the video from the video.js site, but it does not load on my iPhone

```
<source src="/static/videos/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4></source>
```

Codecs for the videos I am trying out all have AAC and H.264 codecs and are mp4s

I have also tried converting my video files to iPhone ready mp4 files using Miro Video Converter but still no luck with loading on the webpage

I am testing on localhost and am using nginx and flask

After more testing: according to the Chrome inspector I am getting response headers back for my video url GET request which explains why it plays on the desktop web. However, for iPhone, the Safari inspector says that I am not getting response headers back. And on Android, I do not get response headers back either, but for some reason the video is still able to play in the webpage on my Android device.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It could be your host server setup. For example when I use Go Daddy, SVG files won't display on my site. You can either check out the config or add a file that allows the MIME type. More on MIME types here: http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx

Comment: I have tried setting mime types on my host server setup - video/mp4 is in the mime.types file. See edited question above for more info that I have found

Comment: @yfu One thing you should try is taking out the </source> closing tags. The HTML source tag is self-closing.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the video extension to **.mov**.

Comment: I tried every possible solution but changing extension to .mov worked.